# Dúvidas quanto a utilização de arquivos .dbml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework

Peguei um sistema em aspx(VS2008) e terei de fazer algumas melhorias, acrescentar outras funcionalidades e tudo isso usando o MVC5. Bem, há um web service, que tem um cara assim:

```
static Func<lqDataDataContext, T_PDV, IQueryable<T_PDV>>
            qryConsPdv = CompiledQuery.Compile(
            (lqDataDataContext lqPT, T_PDV p) =>
                lqPT.T_PDVs.Where(i =>
                    i.CNPJ.Contains(p.CNPJ) &&
                    i.RazaoSocial.Contains(p.RazaoSocial)//== (cnpj == "" ? i.CNPJ : cnpj)
                    ));
```

A questão é que o lqData é um arquivo .dbml. No meu MVC eu gerei alguns arquivo .edmx. A pergunta é: Devo substituir o .dbml pelo .edmx? Se sim, como fazer isso? Confesso que ainda não entendi o código postado. Sei que o dbml é como o edmx, mas qual a diferença entre ambos?

T_PDV é uma entidade do BD. Não entendi o que o delegate faz. Estou lendo e interpretando o código acima, pois necessito reescrever o site em MVC adicionando novas funcionalidades. Esse é meu cenário hoje.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **edmx** é o arquivo de modelagem para o Entity Framework;
- **dbml** é o arquivo de modelagem para o LINQ-2-SQL.

O LINQ-2-SQL é um padrão depreciado, então é bem recomendado que você troque tudo para o **edmx**.

Pra converter, basicamente tem que seguir as instruções [deste link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/efdesign/linq-to-sql-to-entity-framework-conversion-template) na MSDN.

Sobre sua `CompiledQuery`, funciona da seguinte forma:

- `IQueryable` é uma interface que indica um objeto que implementa uma coleção de objetos do tipo `T_PDV` tal que essa coleção possa realizar algumas operações através de **métodos de extensão**, como o método `Where`;
- `qryConsPdv`, portanto, é um delegate que opera em cima de uma coleção `IQueryable<T_PDV>` (uma `List<T_PDV>`, por exemplo) e pede dois argumentos pra funcionar: o primeiro é um `lqDataDataContext` (deve ser um contexto de dados) e o segundo é um objeto do tipo `T_PDV`;
- Por fim, o que o delegate faz é conferir no seu contexto se o objeto passado como segundo parâmetro do `delegate` existe no contexto passado como primeiro parâmetro, conferindo se algum objeto tem o mesmo CNPJ e a mesma Razão Social.

Comment: Veja que ele usa o delegate FUNC<>. Eu gostaria de saber o motivo do delegate, aliás, tenho tido dificuldades com delegate. Realmente estou tentando entender o código acima para eu refazer o meu web service.

Comment: Bom, isto é uma nova dúvida, certo? Acho que é o caso de você abrir uma nova pergunta.

Comment: É isso que eu gostaria de entender. Não é uma nova dúvida. Conforme disse no post original, eu não entendi o código e isso fez o post. Não é uma nova dúvida.

Comment: Veja, são duas dúvidas bem diferentes. Uma está relacionada com o uso de arquivos, e outra está relacionada em entender o código. Por isso acho que você deve fazer outra pergunta para obter a resposta **apenas** quanto à dúvida do `delegate`, que é pertinente. Mas posso responder essa parte também sem problemas, na mesma perguntam se assim for necessário.

Comment: Ok, claro que quero. Mas veja por outro lado. Você posta uma situação, cujo problema está em vários setores. Pô, se você for fazer uma pergunta para cada situação, fica até meio que repetitivo, pois muitas vezes o código é o mesmo. Num código temos muitos fatores, que se desmembrar para fazer uma pergunta para cada será feita, mas repetindo o código várias vezes. Às vezes a pergunta leva consigo N dúvidas, como essa por exemplo, que um problema com dbml me levou a não entender o porque do delegate, o queryable e etc.... Tudo na mesma dúvida. baixei alguma coisa de queryable e delegate p/ ler.

Comment: @pnet Atualizei a resposta.